# How can i display marker with weather information in google maps api android ? Or others method that can show the destination's weather

Tags: android, google-maps, weather, weather-api

```
public class MapsActivity extends Activity {

private static LatLng goodLatLng = new LatLng(37, -120);
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private EditText et_address, et_finalAddress;
LatLng addressPos, finalAddressPos;
Marker addressMarker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    et_address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressEditText);
    et_finalAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalAddressEditText);


    // Initial Map
    try {

        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    // 3D building
    googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
    // Get zoom button
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(goodLatLng)
            .title("Hello"));
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void showAddressMarker(View view) {

     String newAddress = et_address.getText().toString();

    if (newAddress != null) {
        new PlaceAMarker().execute(newAddress);
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
    }
}

public void getDirections(View view) {

    String startingAddress = et_address.getText().toString();
    String finalAddress = et_finalAddress.getText().toString();

    if ((startingAddress.equals("")) || finalAddress.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter a starting and Ending address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        new GetDirections().execute(startingAddress, finalAddress);
    }
}

class PlaceAMarker extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String startAddress = params[0];
        startAddress = startAddress.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

        getLatLng(startAddress, false);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        addressMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(addressPos).title("Address"));
    }
}

class GetDirections extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String startAddress =  params[0];
        startAddress = startAddress.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        getLatLng(startAddress, false);

        String endingAddress = params[1];
        endingAddress = endingAddress.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        getLatLng(endingAddress, true);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        String geoUriString = "http://maps.google.com/maps?addr=" +
                addressPos.latitude + "," +
                addressPos.longitude + "&daddr=" +
                finalAddressPos.latitude + "," +
                finalAddressPos.longitude;

        Intent mapCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(geoUriString));
        startActivity(mapCall);
    }
}

protected void getLatLng(String address, boolean setDestination) {
    String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
            + address + "&sensor=false";

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();

        int byteData;
        while ((byteData = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) byteData);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    double lat = 0.0, lng = 0.0;

    JSONObject jsonObject;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        lng = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                .getDouble("lng");
        lat = ((JSONArray) jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                .getDouble("lat");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (setDestination) {
        finalAddressPos = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    } else {
        addressPos = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    }

}
}
```

This is what i have now which is let user inputting both address and i want to show the weather of the destination of the user input. I am new to java language , hope you guys can help me to solve my problem as stated. Thanks